# How can I read attribute and nested XML

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing

please help me to solve the problem, how can I read attribute and nested XML. I don't understand the principle and I'd like to teach this on the real example.

**Source xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:listUserResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">
      <return>
        <user uuid="{A00B47CC-0C4F-40E7-1E25-22E54FBA4596}">
          <firstName>Name1</firstName>
          <middleName />
          <lastName>Surname1</lastName>
          <primaryExtension>
            <pattern>201</pattern>
          </primaryExtension>
        </user>
        <user uuid="{834E86FA-FDC2-21FE-1E1E-FD164AF23B44}">
          <firstName>Name2</firstName>
          <middleName />
          <lastName>Surname2</lastName>
          <primaryExtension>
            <pattern>202</pattern>
          </primaryExtension>
        </user>
        <user uuid="{798E04E7-0E10-0278-6FAD-EA6A85EF2B2E}">
          <firstName>Name3</firstName>
          <middleName />
          <lastName>Surname3</lastName>
          <primaryExtension>
            <pattern>203</pattern>
          </primaryExtension>
        </user>
      </return>
    </ns:listUserResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to read user uuid attribute and all nodes to append to DataTable. But I don't know how I can read attribute and nested xml (error: "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.")

My code:

```
XmlDocument xmldocListUser = new XmlDocument();
xmldocListUser.LoadXml(soapresultListUser);

// prepare data (like database)
DataTable datatableListUser = new DataTable();
datatableListUser.Clear();
datatableListUser.Columns.Add("uuid");
datatableListUser.Columns.Add("firstName");
datatableListUser.Columns.Add("middleName");
datatableListUser.Columns.Add("lastName");
datatableListUser.Columns.Add("primaryExtensionPattern");

XmlNodeList xnList = xmldocListUser.SelectNodes("//return/user");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    DataRow myDataRow = datatableListUser.NewRow();

    myDataRow["firstName"] = xn["firstName"].InnerText;
    myDataRow["middleName"] = xn["middleName"].InnerText;
    myDataRow["lastName"] = xn["lastName"].InnerText;

    // error
    //myDataRow["uuid"] = xn["@uuid"].InnerText;

    // error
    //string xnDN = xn.SelectSingleNode("//primaryExtension/Pattern").InnerXml;

    // error

    //XmlElement xmlelementEndUserUserId = xmldocGetPhone.DocumentElement;
    //string strEndUserUserId = xn.SelectSingleNode("/primaryExtension/Pattern").InnerXml;
    //myDataRow["primaryExtensionPattern"] = strEndUserUserId; // xn["/primaryExtension/Pattern"].InnerText;

    datatableListUser.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
}
```

Thank you and best regards,
 Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable datatableListUser = new DataTable();
            datatableListUser.Clear();
            datatableListUser.Columns.Add("uuid");
            datatableListUser.Columns.Add("firstName", typeof(string));
            datatableListUser.Columns.Add("middleName", typeof(string));
            datatableListUser.Columns.Add("lastName", typeof(string));
            datatableListUser.Columns.Add("primaryExtensionPattern", typeof(int));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement user in doc.Descendants("user"))
            {
                datatableListUser.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                   (string)user.Attribute("uuid"),
                   (string)user.Element("firstName"),
                   (string)user.Element("middleName"),
                   (string)user.Element("lastName"),
                   (int)user.Descendants("pattern").FirstOrDefault()
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        string uuid = (xn as XmlElement).GetAttribute("uuid");
        string firstName = xn.SelectSingleNode("./firstName").InnerText;
        string middleName= xn.SelectSingleNode("./middleName").InnerText;
        string lastName = xn.SelectSingleNode("./lastName").InnerText;
        string primaryExtensionPattern = xn.SelectSingleNode("./primaryExtensionPattern /pattern").InnerText;

        ...
    }
```

Or you might consider using Linq to XML and use XElement. For me, seems to be easier to parse XMLs